# Inequalities in asymptotic recurrences

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory

The following is from the book "Algorithmics Theory & Practice" (Gilles Brassard and Paul Bratley), page 47.

I tried but could not prove the part highlighted in yellow. f(n) is f(n), t(n) is t(n), and I don't see any relation between f(n) and t(n) unless I can define f(n) = g(t(n)) in some way? Could someone shed me a light?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out how to do it.

[image]

[image]